# Link a select box to a checkbox (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select list:

```
 <select ng-model='myFriend' ng-options='person.name for person in people'>
      <option value=''>-- choose friend --</option>
 </select>
```

And some data:

```
 $scope.people = [
      {name: 'Tyler Durden', online: true, image: 'tyler_durden.jpg'},
      {name: 'Darth Vader', online: true, image: 'darth_vader.jpg'},
      {name: 'The Joker', online: true, image: 'the_joker.jpg'},
 ];
```

I want to add a checkbox beside the select box that will hold the online status of the friend selected in the select box. I'm not sure how to go about doing that though.

Comment: Do you really need a check-box (i.e. full-blown control) or just a check-mark?

Comment: I want the checkbox to also be used for turning on or off online status of the selected friend.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to **filter** either all or on-line only friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually just about there with what you already have. Since you already have myFriend bound to the currently selected option, you can just call for whatever information you need:

```
<select ng-model='myFriend' ng-options='person.name for person in people'>
    <option value=''>-- choose friend --</option>
    <p>{{myFriend.online}}</p>
</select>
```

Here's a demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JdLby/ (It's not a checkbox, but once you have the value you can do whatever you want with it)